# Customizing output of ko.mapping.toJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Is it possible to customize the outputted Javascript of ko.mapping.toJS?

ie-

Only return some of the observable / some properties of the observableArray?

Comment: Here are the docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html.  There are various options to customize how objects are created.

Comment: yes, it details clearly how view model objects can be created, but not the other way around.... ie- JS from viewModels

Comment: For best explanation you can read official documentation:http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking whether it's possible to customize the JS outputted from calling .toJS?

There's nothing built-in for that, but you can certainly just modify the outputted JS object yourself:

```
var myViewModel = ...;
var jsViewModel = ko.mapping.toJS(myViewModel);

// Customize the result
jsViewModel.Foo = "bar";
```